# display data in different div based on an option selection in vue js

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js

I am trying to make a todo app using vue js and element form.I have managed to store the data from the form and display it using vue js but it currently shows in all the three columns.I don't know how to show these items in a specific div.For example, if a user selects an option todo, the data should be shown in todo column and if the user selects the In progress option, data should be shown in the In progress column.I have searched for this on many sites but unfortunately, I didn't find a solution.

Also, The second problem is, the data which is shown in the div doesn't add when submitting another form.It shows in already generated cards.That means, it should generate new card on next form submission.

I am using vuex for storing the data.

Here is the code on which I have worked:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
<head>
<title>--</title>
<style>
.main{
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 5px;
    background: #e7e7e7;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 15px solid #e7e7e7;
    height: 70vh;

}
.heading{
    background: #c2c8f1;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 10px;
}
.details{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    row-gap: 5px;
}

.column{
    background: #d7d7d7;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.add{
    border: 1px solid #0479cbf7;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #0479cbf7;
    align-self: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in;
    background:transparent;
}

.add:hover{
    background: #0479cbf7;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.add:target{
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.tasks{
    display: flex;
}
.tasks h2{
    margin-top: auto;
}
#app{
    margin-left: auto;
}
.el-drawer__header{
    padding: 20px 10px;
    background: #eaeaea;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.drawer__footer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.el-drawer__body>*{
    text-indent: 10px;
}
.el-form-item__content{
    display: grid;
}
.el-form-item__label{
    text-align: start;
}
.drawer{
    width: 45%!important;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.el-form-item{
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.el-drawer__close-btn, #el-drawer__title{
    display: none!important;
}
.close{
    float: right;
}
.close:before{
    content: '\00d7';
    cursor: pointer;
}
.el-message-box__btns{
    display: flex;
}
.el-date-editor--date,.el-date-editor--time{
    width: 100%!important;
}
.desc{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px; 
}
.el-textarea__inner{
    min-height: 100px!important;
}
.card{
    background:white;
    border-left: 3px solid #00ca00;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width:  80%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#card1{
    border-left: 3px solid #f0667f;
}
.card p:nth-child(1){
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.card p:nth-child(2){
    color:blue;
    font-size: 19px;

}
.card p:nth-child(3){
    color:red;
}

.card p span:before{
    content: '\01F642';
    float:right;
    visibility:hidden;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">
<div id="app">
<div class="tasks" style="margin-bottom:auto;">
<h2>My Tasks</h2>
<template>
<el-button class="add" @click="dialog = true">Add Task</el-button>
<el-drawer
  title="Add New Task"
  :visible.sync="dialog"
  :before-close="submitForm"
  direction="rtl"
  custom-class="drawer"
  ref="drawer"
  >
  <div class="el-drawer__header">
  <span role="heading" title="Add New Task">Add New Task</span>
  <div class="close" @click="cancelForm()"></div>
</div>
  <div class="drawer__content">
    <el-form :model="form" :rules="rules" ref="form" class="demo-ruleForm">
      <el-form-item label="Task Name" :label-width="formLabelWidth" prop="name" required>
        <el-input v-model="form.name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="please input"></el-input>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Description" :label-width="formLabelWidth" class="desc">
      <el-input type="textarea" v-model="form.desc"></el-input>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Account" :label-width="formLabelWidth" prop="account" required>
        <el-input v-model="form.account" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type account name for remote search"></el-input>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Assigned To" :label-width="formLabelWidth" prop="assigned" required>
        <el-select v-model="form.assigned">
          <el-option label="team1" value="team1"></el-option>
          <el-option label="team2" value="team2"></el-option>
        </el-select>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Status" :label-width="formLabelWidth" prop="status" required>
        <el-select id="target" v-model="form.status">
          <el-option label="to-do" value="to-do"></el-option>
          <el-option label="in-progress" value="in-progress"></el-option>
          <el-option label="done" value="done"></el-option>
        </el-select>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Priorty" :label-width="formLabelWidth" prop="priorty" required>
        <el-select v-model="form.priorty">
          <el-option label="high" value="high"></el-option>
          <el-option label="medium" value="medium"></el-option>
          <el-option label="low" value="low"></el-option>
        </el-select>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Due Date" :label-width="formLabelWidth" prop="date" required>
      <el-date-picker
      v-model="form.date"
      type="date"
      placeholder="Pick a Date"
      format="yyyy/MM/dd">
      </el-date-picker>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Due Time" :label-width="formLabelWidth" prop="time" required>
        <el-time-picker
        v-model="form.time"
        :picker-options="{
        selectableRange: '00:00:00 - 23:59:59'
        }"
        placeholder="Pick a time">
        </el-time-picker>
      </el-form-item>
    </el-form>
    <el-divider></el-divider>
    <div class="drawer__footer">
      <el-button @click="cancelForm()">Cancel</el-button>
      <el-button class="btn" type="primary" @click="submitForm('form')" :loading="loading">{{ loading ? 'Submitting ...' : 'Save' }}</el-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</el-drawer>
</template>
</div>
<section class="main">
<div class="details">
<div class="heading heading1">
<h4>To Do</h4>
</div>
<div class="column first">
<div class="card" id="card1">
            <p class="form-item">{{ getItemData.name }}</p>
            <p class="form-item">{{ getItemData.account }}</p>
            <p class="form-item">{{ getItemData.date }}</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="details">
<div class="heading heading2">
<h4>In Progress</h4>
</div>
<div class="column second">
<div class="card" id="card2">
            <p class="form-item">{{ getItemData.name }}</p>
            <p class="form-item">{{ getItemData.account }}</p>
            <p class="form-item">{{ getItemData.date }}</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="details">
<div class="heading heading3">
<h4>Completed in last 30 days</h4>
</div>
<div class="column third">
<div class="card" id="card3">
            <p class="form-item">{{ getItemData.name }}</p>
            <p class="form-item">{{ getItemData.account }}</p>
            <p class="form-item">{{ getItemData.date }}</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</section>
</div>
</div>
<script src="assets/vendor/jquery/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/umd/locale/en.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.2.0/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<script>


ELEMENT.locale(ELEMENT.lang.en)

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    form: {
      name: '',
      desc: '',
      account: '',
      assigned: '',
      status: '',
      priorty:'',
      date: '',
      time: ''
      
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_ITEM(state, payload) {
      // mutate state
      state.form = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    addItem ({ commit },payload) {
      commit('ADD_ITEM', payload)
    }
  },
  getters: {
    itemData: state => {
      return state.form
    }
  }
})


var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false,
      loading: false,
      form: {
        name: '',
        desc: '',
        account: '',
        assigned: '',
        status: '',
        priorty:'',
        date: '',
        time: ''
      },
      rules: {
          name: [
            { required: true, message: 'Please input Task Name', trigger: 'blur' },
            { min: 3, max: 15, message: 'Length should be 3 to 5', trigger: 'blur' }
          ],
          account: [
            { required: true, message: 'Please input Account Name', trigger: 'change' }
          ],
          assigned: [
            { required: true, message: 'Please select Member Name', trigger: 'change' }
          ],
          status: [
            { required: true, message: 'Please Enter status', trigger: 'change' }
          ],
          priorty: [
            { required: true, message: 'Please select priorty', trigger: 'change' }
          ],
          date: [
            { type: 'date', required: true, message: 'Please pick a Date', trigger: 'change' }
          ],
          time: [
            { type: 'date', required: true, message: 'Please pick a time', trigger: 'change' }
          ]
        },
      formLabelWidth: '110px',
      timer: null,
    };
    
  },
  store,
  methods: {
      cancelForm() {
        this.dialog = false
        this.loading = false   
        clearTimeout(this.timer);

      },
      
      submitForm(formName) {
        
        this.$refs[formName].validate((valid) => {
          if (valid) {
             this.$confirm('Do you want to submit?')
        .then(_ => {
          this.loading = true;
          this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
            // animation takes time
            setTimeout(() => {
              alert('Form Submitted')
              this.loading = false;
              this.dialog = false;
              this.form.date = moment(this.form.date).fromNow();
              this.$store.dispatch('addItem', this.form)


            }, 400);
          }, 2000);
        })
        .catch(_ => {
         
        }); 

          } else {
            console.log('error submit!!');
            return false;
          }
        });
      }
    },
    computed: {
     getItemData() {
        return this.$store.getters.itemData
     }
    },
    watch: {
        form: function() {
            console.log(this.form)
        }
        }
}

var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have put the code in a single html file so that there is no difficulty in running.Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you need to modify some parts on your Vuex store:

1. Create a item in your state called `tasks` of type array:

```
    tasks: []
```

2. Modify your mutation `ADD_ITEM` to push your payload to the new state `tasks`:

```
    ADD_ITEM(state, payload) {
      // mutate state
      state.tasks.push(payload)
    }
```

3. You need to create some Vuex getters to retrieve the tasks filtered by status, so, if you want to only retrieve tasks with the to-do status this getter can help you:

```
    todoItems: state => {
      return state.tasks.filter(item => item.status === 'to-do')
    }
```

Finally, you need to modify your TO-DO column to traverse all the to-do tasks from your store:

```
   <div v-for="item in getToDoItems" class="card" id="card1">
     <p class="form-item">{{ item.name }}</p>
     <p class="form-item">{{ item.account }}</p>
     <p class="form-item">{{ item.date }}</p>
   </div>
```

And voilá, now you can get your task filtered by status for each column. You need to do this to each status.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I will check it and let you know if this works.

Comment: I had to modify your code to get it done.Nice work.Thank you.